# SQl invalid column error. works in sql developer, gives error in java

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, oracle11g

When I run this query : `select emp.emp_name as "name" from emp order by name.`
This runs fine from sqldeveloper. But through java, using a hibernate session, this gives an sql :`invalid column error.`
Why is this difference in behavior?
EDIT: The error says Invalid Column :NAME (in upper case) and not name. I will try this:

select emp.emp_name as "name" from emp order by "name"

Comment: Are you trying to execute this as a Hibernate Query Language (HQL) query? If so, it needs to be rewritten to use class and property names instead of table and column names.

Comment: @Rob:no..SQL query in hibernate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see my EDIT. It solved the issue.

Answer (score 4):

The name "name" is likely a reserved keyword.  sql developer is being forgiving.  Try

```
select emp.emp_name as [name] from emp order by [name]
```

or better yet, just don't use a reserved keyword, or even a *possibly* reserved keyword.

Even if this is not the issue (which it might not be depending on your platform/rdbms), you should avoid column names like "type", "DateTime", etc. for the sole purpose of code readability, reserved words conflicts aside.

Comment: I find it's worth subclassing Hibernate's `DefaultNamingScheme` to quote all table/column identifiers, which it really should be doing already.